# Find path between two nodes in a tree (a simple connected tree not of any specific type)

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, graph-theory

I want to find path between two nodes of a tree .Most of the methods that i found on web are related to graphs and may be complexity is more in case of graph than trees (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-paths-given-source-destination/)
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-paths-given-source-destination-using-bfs/

Comment: It doesn't get much simpler than depth first search (DFS).

Comment: does the dfs uses less time compared to the bfs one ?

Comment: That probably depends on the geometry of the tree. Bredth first search will find short paths quicker but probably has a higher overhead. But you asked about simplicity and DFS is the simplest

Answer (score 1):

You will need to search in the tree. Since we do not have any additional innformation, we do not have any clues where to look at, so it will either be a [depth-first search](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dfs-traversal-of-a-tree-using-recursion/), or [breadth-first search](https://www.cs.bu.edu/teaching/cs112/spring-2000/breadth-first/). When your nodes are found, you will know the path, so you can stop the search. If you need further optimization, then you will need to find some additional pattern in your data-source.

Comment: suppose it is tree and i am applying bfs for graphs (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-paths-given-source-destination-using-bfs/)(tree is special case of graphs) then will  it hamper time complexity or i need to modify bfs according to tree

Comment: @boucher in a graph, due to the fact that cycles are possible there is a habit to assign a "color" to nodes which were not visited yet and change it at the time of the first visit to avoid infinite loops. You do not need that, because trees, by definition are connected, cycle-less graphs. Also, you do not need to worry of node "islands" either, because the tree is connected.